# RSA-OAEP: How does it work?

Tags: rsa, oaep

I was looking at this image about OAEP:

[image]

..and was wondering what was happening here.

1. We have a data block `DB` which consists of:

   - `lHash`: What is this and where does this come from?
   - `PS`: A string of zeros, but how much zeros?
   - `M`: clearly our message.
2. We have a `seed` which , is some random number. We put this seed into a `MGF`, a Mask Generating Function, and XOR the outcome with the `MB`. This is our `maskedDB`. Correct?
3. We put the  `maskedDB` to the `MGF` again and XOR it with the `seed`. This is our `maskedSeed`.
4. For the final `EM` (encrypted message) we prepend some zeros. What do we do with `EM` then?

Comment: WTF! OAEP only uses a two round Feistel network?! That's not even enough to be a random permutation (requires 3 rounds) let alone a strong random permutation (requires 4 rounds).

Comment: @CodesInChaos OAEP is a padding scheme, not an encryption algorithm. Its output is random enough for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1a lHash: What is this and where does this come from?***

That's in [PKCS#1 v2.1: RSAES-OAEP-ENCRYPT ((n, e), M, L):](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.1.1)

> 2a. If the label L is not provided, let L be the empty string. Let
> lHash = Hash(L), an octet string of length hLen (see the note
> below).

***1b) PS: A string of zeros, but how much zeros?***

Similarly for this question, lets look at the actual standard:

> 2b. Generate an octet string PS consisting of k - mLen - 2hLen - 2
> zero octets.  The length of PS may be zero.

***2) We have a seed which , is some random number. We put this seed into a MGF, a Mask Generating Function, and XOR the outcome with the MB. This is our maskedDB. Correct?***

Well, yes, but you XOR with DB, not with MB (whatever that is). It's in steps 2c..2f of the linked section of PKCS#1.

***3) We put the maskedDB to the MGF again and XOR it with the seed. This is our maskedSeed.***

***4) For the final EM (encrypted message) we prepend some zeros. What do we do with EM then?***

You continue with steps 3a..c and of course step 4 of the standard, which basically means:

- 3a) creating an integer from the octet string you've just constructed
- 3b) modular exponentiation with the public exponent and modulus of the public key (also known as raw or textbook RSA)
- 3c) creating an octet string from the result again

And 4, output the result (well...duh).

Comment: ...the EM is given to the standard RSA?

Comment: @今天春天: yes, except that what you call _"standard RSA"_ is hardly standardized (though close to PKCS#1v1.5 format 0), and usually is called _textbook RSA encryption_,  _RSA encryption with no padding_, (_textbook|raw|bare|naked) RSA public-key|encryption primitive|function_. More strictly speaking, _RSA Encryption Primitive_ , noted RSAEP, is step 3b).

Comment: seed length equals hLen, the result of hashing seed is something its length depends on hash algorithm (sha1: 20 bytes, sha256: 32 bytes...). how it can be k - hLen - 1 as PKCS#1 said?